# I want to append a list of numbers to another list; using another list for the range of appending

Tags: python-2.7

Just to be clear there are 3 different lists involved. la is a list of integers and the posfinList is a list of numbers where each integer from la should be appended until it reaches the first number in the list then moves to the next in the posfinList. The numbers in posfinList will change everytime I use different data.

```
posfinList=[83, 81, 83, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 86, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 85, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83]
```

la is a list of 6,932 integers

```
rosen = 0
blos=0
lafin = []
lafins=[]


while rosen<len(la):
    while rosen<(posfinList[blos]):
        lafin.append(la[rosen])
        if rosen >=(posfinList[blos]):
            lafins.append(lafin)

            blos+=1
        rosen+=1
print lafins
```

Comment: When I run the program it seems like it is going through an infinite loop so how do I make this run properly

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  Could you clarify please?  Or even better, what output would you expect for this input?:

```
la=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
posfinList=[2, 4, 6]
```

(StackOverflow people: Yes, I know that should be a comment, but I don't have the reputation for it yet!)

Even without a clarification, however, I can confirm that you have an infinite loop. If `posfinList[0]<6932`, as it is in your example, then the inner loop terminates with `rosen=posfinList[0]` and `rosen` has no way to increase or reset.  The outer loop continues and never terminates, causing the infinite loop you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to chop up the list `la` into several pieces, so that the `n`:th piece has a length equal to `posfinList[n]` for all `n`. Please confirm/deny.

---

The following code is based on that assumption, see if it works the way you want:

```py
lafins = []

for p in postfinList:
    lafins.append( la[rosen:rosen+p] )
    rosen += p
```

(If `la[rosen:rosen+p]` is unfamiliar notation to you, you can read about it (it's called 'slice' notation) in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). You'll find the relevant bits a little way down under the 'Strings' header.)

I have mostly used the same variable names as you, though they're not all that descriptive. Taking the time to choose variable names that actually document what the variables do generally pays off handsomely when testing and debugging, not to mention helps to make sure that you yourself know what those variables are meant to do.

---

As for your original code, there are at least three problems:

- the stuff inside `if rosen >=(posfinList[blos])` will never execute. The `if` itself is contained in `while rosen<(posfinList[blos])`, which actually makes sure that `rosen>=(postfinList[blos])` will never be true inside it.
- when `while rosen<(posfinList[blos])` exits (unless by coincidence `rosen>=len(la)`), `while rosen<len(la)` will enter an infinite loop: `rosen` will always be less than `len(la)`. Neither of those values will ever change again, so the `while` condition will always be true.
- this one is difficult to explain, so I'm just going to say this: for your loop to work, in the example case you gave, `postfinList` should be `[83, 164, 247, 329, ...]` instead of `[83, 81, 83, 82, ...]`, that is, it should be `[83, 83+81, 83+81+83, 83+81+83+82, ...]`. Think about why that is.